# Piecing together a diagram from other files

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, arrows, landscape

I'm in `\documentaclass[landscape]{article}` and I'm trying to figure out how I can put together a bunch of figures I've created (with the generous help of TSE users) on this document.

What I'm trying to do is this

[image: Diagram]

I've tried using help grid to at least get the arrows in place, but the grid keeps shifting every time I add something.

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor} 
\documentclass[landscape]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepgflibrary{decorations.shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes, arrows, decorations.markings, shapes, fit, arrows, positioning, trees, mindmap, calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% figures

% text

% figures

% text

% and last time down 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Since I don't have a minimal working code, I don't expect to magically work this out for me, but any advice or examples would be helpful.

Comment: Have you tried using `includegraphic` in nodes?

Comment: @Raphael Do you mean to literally import a tikz figure into a node, like a circle node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have figures as some kind of image file (including PDF and somesuch), you can simply use `includegraphics` in node texts. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
    \node (center) {some text here};

    \node[above left=of center]  (fig1) {\includegraphics{smile.pdf}};
    \node[below left=of center]  (fig2) {\includegraphics{smile.pdf}};
    \node[above right=of center] (fig3) {\includegraphics{smile.pdf}};
    \node[below right=of center] (fig4) {\includegraphics{smile.pdf}};
    \node[above=of fig4,align=center] (rcenter) {some more \\ text};


    \draw[double] (fig1) -- (center)
                  (fig3) -- (center)
                  (fig4) -- (rcenter);
    \draw[double,-stealth]  (center) -- (fig2);
    \draw[double,-stealth]  (center) -- (fig4);
    \draw[double,-stealth]  (rcenter) -- (fig3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This code compiles to:

[image]

As you can see, the arrows line up automatically since regular paths always anchor at the `center` anchor by default. If your figures resp. their spacing is not as regular, you might want to look into layers, draw the arrows first and then the text nodes over them.

In order to get PDFs out of TikZ code, you can use [`standalone`](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,wasysym}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node {\smiley};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This compiles to the smiley image seen above, that is in particular without superfluous whitespace.

Comment: Do I need to include the file location in `includegraphics`? I keep getting an error. (Of course, I replaced smile.pdf with my own pdf).

Comment: @AlanH Yes, you need to give a path to the file.